# Electronic Touch Screen for Agile Task/Story Wall

Tags: project-management

We want to replace our 10 'normal' whiteboards used for Agile/Scrum task/story walls with a single touch screen electronic whiteboard.

We are not looking for a full project management app, just the whiteboard part.
We are looking at using a (very) big touch screen for the white board.

Has anyone seen any app/software that can do this?
Suggestions, recommendations, warnings?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the hardware suggestions, but we are really looking for 'Task/Story Wall' software which can run on an electronic whiteboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you want hardware recommendation, but [Smartboards](http://smarttech.com/) are great. Used extensively in schools, easy and intuitive, tough and durable, but not (unless they have newer products) multi-touch.

Answer (score 1):

We've used [Teamboards](http://www.teamboard.com) for a while, although not directly on agile projects. Good features include:

- The ability to write on them with std whiteboard pens as well as electronic
  pens
- Acting as a projector screen as well as a whiteboard

From an Agile project perspective, I think they would make good story boards, particularly to save/restore story card walls, burn down charts, etc and it also gives you a nice space to project your backlog onto